# Use ImageDataGenerator to make train test AND validation sets?

Tags: python, keras

I can see general questions talking about how to use ImageDataGenerator from keras to develop training and validation sets (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443936/keras-split-train-test-set-when-using-imagedatagenerator)).

I have a CSV file of image names, and a binary label of each image. I want to divide that up into a set of training, validation and test set.

I wrote this:

```
traindf=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/images_and_labels.txt',dtype=str,sep='\s')
traindf.columns = ['image','label','none1','none2','none3']
traindf.drop(['none1', 'none2','none3'], axis=1)

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
  dataframe=traindf,
  directory="/content/drive/",
  x_col="image",
  y_col="label",
  subset="training",
  batch_size=32,
  seed=42,
  shuffle=True,
  class_mode="categorical",
  target_size=(150,150)
)

validation_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
  dataframe=traindf,
  directory="/content/drive/",
  x_col="image",
  y_col="label",
  subset="validation",
  batch_size=32,
  seed=42,
  shuffle=True,
  class_mode="categorical",
  target_size=(150,150)
)
```

What I don't understand is how to split that into three data sets, training, test and validation?

When I just try to make another generator called test with:

test_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=traindf,
directory="/content/drive/",
x_col="image",
y_col="label",
subset="test",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(150,150)
)

I get: `ValueError: Invalid subset name: test;expected "training" or "validation"`

How do I use ImageDataGenerator to divide a CSV file into three data sets, training, validation and test, so I can build a model with train and validation, and then test on test at the end? I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952231/keras-how-to-expand-validation-split-to-generate-a-third-set-i-e-test-set?rq=1) that it was not possible to do, but that question was >3.5 years ago, am wondering if it is now possible?

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is just create a separate dataframe for your test data. You could even automatically split it using another script. Then you can just load that new dataframe as your test data:

```
test_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
test_df,
directory=image_dir,
x_col='filename',
y_col='labels',
class_mode='categorical',
shuffle=False,
target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
batch_size=1)
```