# Multiple ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to generate two parameters from ImageDataGenerator for input to my model.fit_generator() but that don't work, I don't now if is the best way to do that.

My structure is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA1sn.png)

```
input_imgen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, 
                                  vertical_flip=True, 
                                  validation_split=0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip = True)

input_imgen2 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255, 
                                  shear_range = 0.2, 
                                  zoom_range = 0.2,
                                  rotation_range=5.)

testgenerator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

def generate_generator_multiple(generator1, generator2, train_data_dir, batch_size, img_height, 
img_width):
genX1 = generator1.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                      target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                      class_mode = 'categorical',
                                      batch_size = batch_size,
                                      shuffle=False, 
                                      seed=7)

genX2 = generator2.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                      target_size = (img_height, img_width),
                                      class_mode = 'categorical',
                                      batch_size = batch_size,
                                      shuffle=False, 
                                      seed=7)
while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]  #Yield both images and their mutual label


data_gen_train=generate_generator_multiple(generator1=input_imgen1,
                                           generator2=input_imgen2,
                                           train_data_dir=train_dir,
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           img_height=IMG_HEIGHT,
                                           img_width=IMG_WIDTH)    
history = model.fit_generator(
    data_gen_train,
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=25,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=testgenerator,
    validation_steps=25,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stop, tensor_board]
)
```

Error when I fit:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4QV5.png)

Comment: Maybe here you find answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443936/keras-split-train-test-set-when-using-imagedatagenerator

Answer (score 0):

As evident from the logs your error is caused during validation **data_gen_valid** should be constructed the same way as **data_gen_train** .

So if your training data has been the concatenation of two generators so should be your validation data.