# How to build multi-input image process by Tensorflow ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I am attempting to build a multi-input CNN model.
Specifically, the model classifies the words "arigatou, hai,..." into 20 types as shown in the attached image.
into 20 types of words.
This is a good example.
For this purpose, the input format we are assuming is to input images from 4 channels simultaneously.

However, I am having trouble figuring out how to process the image data.

Please let me know if there is a way to use ImageDatageneraror to create training data from a directory structure like an image.

Thank you very much.

sample URL:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator?hl=zh-tw
[Multiple ImageDataGenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907862/multiple-imagedatagenerator?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is make a Pandas Dataframe of all the images paths and then use the ImageDataGenerator on that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.Please show me an example of Pandas Dataframe combined with ImageDataGenerator program.